# Azure Application gateway fails with terminal provisioning state "Failed"

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I am deploying azure application gateway (internal) with V2, it succeeded couple of times in other subscriptions (Environments), however, it is failing with strange error and without much details about the error.

deployment fails after 30 mins of applying/creating

there is a UDR but which is for different purpose and not blocking or restricting the default internet route

[image]

The deployment is using terraform and everything worked well in other instances deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue and resolution

1. Raised a Microsoft case to see the logs of the APPGW at the platform level
2. Microsoft verified the logs and identified that AppGW is not able to communicate with the Keyvault to read the ssl certificate as we are using Keyvault to store ssl cert for TLS encryption
3. Found out that subnet to subnet communication is blocked and hence AppGW is unable to communicate with KV in another subnet

Resolution:
Allowed subnet to subnet communication where appgw and kv are present

Conclusion:
Microsoft would have enabled better logging information (error details) in the AppGW resource deployment and or resource activity logs

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below.***

```xml
"details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"![The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIAK7.png)'.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }
  ]
```

This issue generally occurs, when an unsupported route typically a 0.0.0.0/0 route to a firewall being advertised via BGP is affecting the Application Gateway Subnet.

Try to deploy with a default vnet and manage subnet configuration like below:

[image]

When I tried to deploy, Azure Application gateway deployment succeeded successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

If your deployment fails after 30 mins you can make use of ***diagnose logs*** to check error messages in any logs pertaining to the unsuccessful procedure.

[image]

Once you determine the cause of the issue diagnosis will guide you to take the necessary steps and fix the issue. Resolving network issues, depending on the cause of the failure.

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually UDR was not an issue